# How to solve the error of "Not Acceptable" result while trying fetch html content using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

While trying to fetch data from website, I am not able to get the html content of the website using Beautiful soup.
I am using a basic get functions and requests to get the html, but the output empty.

```
url= 'https://www.turbobearings.com/application.php'
html= (requests.get(url))
soup_= soup(html.content, 'lxml')
newtry= soup_.find('div', 'class', 'kblock kcategories-1')

Result: <html><head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>
```

what can be done to get the html content for this webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the website detects that you are using some kind of an automation tool like `requests` to extract the html code from their website. In order to bypass this, try adding an `user-agent` to your request. The `user-agent` will help you fake your identity and make your request look legit, so the website won't detect you as a bot. Here is how you do it:

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}

url= 'https://www.turbobearings.com/application.php'

html= requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}

url= 'https://www.turbobearings.com/application.php'
html= requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup_= soup(html.content, 'lxml')
newtry= soup_.find('div', 'class', 'kblock kcategories-1')

print(soup_)
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="" lang="en-gb" xml:lang="en-gb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Turbo Bearings Pvt Ltd Rajkot, Gujarat, India</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewports"/>
<meta content="Tapered Roller Bearings, Double Row Tapered Roller Bearings, Cylindrical Roller Bearings, Needle Roller Bearings, Ball Bearings, Rajkot, Gujarat, India" name="Description"/>
<meta content="Tapered Roller Bearings Metric Series, Tapered Roller Bearings Inch Series, Double Row Tapered Roller Bearings, Cylindrical Roller Bearings, Special Cylindrical Roller Bearings, Single Row Full Compliment, Double Row Full Compliment, Needle Roller Bearings, Split Type 2 Needle Roller Bearings, NK Type, Full Compliment Bearings, Ball Bearings, Deep Groove Ball Bearings, Special Ball Bearings, Angular Contact Ball Bearings, Special Angular Contact Ball Bearings, Steering Ball Bearings, Hub Ball Bearings, Thrust Ball Bearings, Thrust Single Direction, Thrust Double Direction, Clutch Bearings, Four Point Contact Bearings, King Pin Bearings, Steering Bearings, Spherical Roller Thrust Bearings, Special Roller Thrust Double Row, Standard Room, Laboratory, Metallurgical Microscope, Profile Projector, Talyrond, Form Talysurf, Roller Sorting Machine, Bearing Noise Level &amp; Vibration Tester, Grinding Facilities, Ring Super Finishing Facilities, Roller Super Finishing Facilites, Assembly and Dispatch Facilities, Laser Marking Machine, Design &amp; Drawing Department, Bearing Endurance (Life) Testing Machine" name="Keywords"/>
<meta content="index,follow" name="robots"/>
<meta content="Turbo Bearings Pvt. Ltd." name="Author"/>
<meta content="global" name="distribution"/>
<meta content="document" name="resource-type"/>
<meta content="http://www.turbobearings.com" name="identifier-url"/>
<meta content="www.turbobearings.com" name="copyright"/>
<meta content="IN" name="country"/>
<meta content="Manufacturers and Exporters" name="rating"/>
<meta content="2 days" name="revisit-after"/>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/lrstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/caroufredsel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/camera.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/default_icemegamenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/default_icemegamenu-reponsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/plugin_googlemap3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;language=en-GB&amp;libraries=places'></script> -->
<script src="js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/additional-methods.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.caroufredsel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/camera.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.rd-navbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/googlemapsv3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/TMSearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',  function() {
                new JCaption('img.caption');
            });
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
});
window.setInterval(function(){var r;try{r=window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(e){}if(r){r.open("GET","./",true);r.send(null)}},840000);
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     RDMobilemenu_autoinit("#icemegamenu");
})
  </script>
<script>
    function GetProduct(prodid)
    {
        var prod_id=document.getElementById(prodid).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('txtSeachProd').value=prod_id;
    }
</script>
<script>
...
```

Comment: I am new to Python, so dont know if how to get the headers info.
where can I get this details of my system

Comment: If you still want to find the headers of your browser by yourself, try typing ```chrome://version/``` in the url bar of ur chrome browser and press enter. Then look for the user agent value and just copy paste it into your code. Simple.

Comment: Tried the same, but while going into particular tag, giving a None result.
in the above code, tried printing the "newtry" value, it generates None

Comment: What "newtry" value? What do u exactly wanna scrape from the website?